# Endless "Mail needs to repair its information about your mailboxes"

Tags: macos, apple-mail, osx-yosemite

Mail keeps popping up this message: "Mail needs to repair its information about your mailboxes"

I click Quit to restart, but it keeps showing up when it's restarted.  I've restarted it about 10 times now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try manually reindexing your mailboxes. There are instructions at  http://www.computerworld.com/article/2476217/mac-os-x/how-to-fix-apple-mail-by-rebuilding-and-reindexing-the-mailbox.html .

Basically, you quit Mail, remove all files starting with "Envelope Index" from ~/Library/Mail/V2/MailData, then start Mail. It will reindex all your messages, and then it should run fine. (At least, this worked for me.)

Comment: This is the step I took back in January.

Comment: Didn't work on macOS Sierra (10.12.1). After deleting the files from `~/Library/Mail/V4/MailData` Mail.app started to re-import the messages, but once it finished the same error started to happen again.

Comment: That said, deleting the whole `~/Library/Mail/V4/MailData` seems to work on Sierra, at least I didn't have the issue for more than a day now.